# vue router example with composition API and SFC

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am working on a vue3 / vuetify project which is growing fast and now has 14 components, some of which are 'grandchild' components. It's generally working well but I am having problems switching between `v-tabs` : sometimes an incorrect component is shown (for example, one tab shows one of four different components depending on a prop)

So I am wondering if using vue-router would help organise my code better. But I cannot find any complete working examples of using vue router with the compostion API. [The 'official' vue router page](https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html) is based on options API with the compostion API seemingly added as an afterthought in the 'advanced' section.

To be clear, I am not asking for advice on wether I should use vue router or not. I just need to see a complete working example, using Composition API and SFC, so that I can decide for myself.

Comment: Everything is mostly the same between the two APIs. The key differences are explained at the top of the [composition API documentation page](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html). Instead of having access to `this.$router`, you first define `router = useRouter()` in your component then carry on as normal. in-component navigation guards (advanced topic) are also done slightly differently now. The configuration of vue-router, creating routes, the usage of `<router-view>` is all the same. The vast majority of the "Options API" documentation also covers Composition API.